# Connect two actionbuttons with display of the same tabItem in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have the shiny app below with 3 actionbuttons in the header section. Each one after clicked now leads to the correspondent tab. What I want to achieve is to make actionbuttons `home` and `tab1` to lead to the same tab `home` while actionbutton `tab2` should lead to the tab `tab2`, as it is now.

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Demo", tags$li(class = "dropdown", actionButton("home", "Home")),
                                  tags$li(class = "dropdown", actionButton("tab1", "Tab1")),
                                  tags$li(class = "dropdown", actionButton("tab2", "Tab2"))),
  dashboardSidebar(width="0px",sidebarMenu(id = "sidebar", # id important for updateTabItems
                               menuItem("Home", tabName = "home", icon = icon("house")),
                               menuItem("Tab1", tabName = "tab1", icon = icon("table")),
                               menuItem("Tab2", tabName = "tab2", icon = icon("line-chart"))
                               )
  ),
  
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem("home", "This is the home tab"),
      tabItem("tab1", "This is Tab1"),
      tabItem("tab2", "This is Tab2")
    ))
)
server = function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$home, {
    updateTabItems(session, "sidebar", "home")
  })
  observeEvent(input$tab1, {
    updateTabItems(session, "sidebar", "tab1")
  })
  observeEvent(input$tab2, {
    updateTabItems(session, "sidebar", "tab2")
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Do you mean `tab2` when you say `tab3`?

Comment: yes sorry u re right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this get what you're looking for? I only changed the third argument in the `observeEvent(input$tab1...`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Demo", tags$li(class = "dropdown", actionButton("home", "Home")),
                  tags$li(class = "dropdown", actionButton("tab1", "Tab1")),
                  tags$li(class = "dropdown", actionButton("tab2", "Tab2"))),
  dashboardSidebar(width="0px",sidebarMenu(id = "sidebar", # id important for updateTabItems
                                           menuItem("Home", tabName = "home", icon = icon("house")),
                                           menuItem("Tab1", tabName = "tab1", icon = icon("table")),
                                           menuItem("Tab2", tabName = "tab2", icon = icon("line-chart"))
  )
  ),
  
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem("home", "This is the home tab"),
      tabItem("tab1", "This is Tab1"),
      tabItem("tab2", "This is Tab2")
    ))
)

server = function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$home, {
    updateTabItems(session, "sidebar", "home")
  })
  observeEvent(input$tab1, {
    updateTabItems(session, "sidebar", "home")
  })
  observeEvent(input$tab2, {
    updateTabItems(session, "sidebar", "tab2")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```